# Java Server and Client Time

Tags: java, timezone

Please can any body help me I have been faced time related problem regarding client and server time display issue since 1 week.

Description:  Actually server is located in Germany when client (example : india) try to send any message to his contacts it will show the message sending time is server time (means Germany time).But I should say local specific time.I user send any then I show message sending time like this.

```
public static String retrieveFullDateFromDateinAMPM ( Date date ) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

Here I send date value to my helper method `retrieveFullDateFromDateinAMPM(Date date)`   and I will return the message sending time like this : `return sdf.format(date);` to the web page. But it shows server located time but I should need to show locale specific time. Please help me.  Advanced Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `Date` does not know anything about specific timezones. You need to call [**`SimpleDateFormat#setTimeZone`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setTimeZone%28java.util.TimeZone%29) to set specific timezones.

Consider code like below setting `IST` (Indian Standard Time) timezone on your `DateFormat` instance:

```
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a", Locale.getDefault());
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));

// Will print the date-time in the IST timezone  
System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

**OR else format the data using [current timezone](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault%28%29) of the system:**

```
sdf.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getDefault() );
```

Comment: If ssy pesters you again please let me know. Comments aren't supposed to drag beyond the question and answer at hand. Especially not over the course of more than a month.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks, I tried telling him many times, even game him my email address.

Answer (score 1):

a server-side solution mandates that the server code knows about the location of the client. i assume that this information will be supplied somehow as a [iso 2-letter code](http://www.iso.org/iso/country_names_and_code_elements). the java api mandates that for the following solution to work the language must also be known. i assume that it can be derived from the country code or is expressly supplied as an [iso 2-/3-letter code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639).

so a revised method might be:

```
public static String retrieveFullDateFromDateinAMPM ( Date date, String lang, String country ) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf =
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm a", Locale ( lang, country ) )
    ;

    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

for more details see [the java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

Answer (score 0):

would it be not better to send to client always UTC ?

Client wold always have information about UTC and could convert it to local time ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set proper locale when parsing/formating a date object. If the locale is properly set in client browser, you should be able to access with `javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getLocale()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I done this from client side.Means after sending server time to client side(html, jsp....) then I write a bit of Jquery code like this.Here please convert the server date into .getTime() at your client side.(example new Date().getTime() == $('#message_creation_time').val())

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var date = new Date(parseInt($('#message_creation_time').val())); 
    var localeSpecificTime = date.toLocaleTimeString().replace(/:\d+ /, ' ');
    var dateString =   date.toDateString();$('.message_creation_time_display').html(dateString+"&nbsp;&nbsp;"+localeSpecificTime);
  });
</script>
```